# Many to Many to Many relationship? (Sub Category Lookup)

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship linked by a table "`farmer2crop`", linking farmers to crop types (e.g. rice, wheat, corn, spices, etc.)

e.g.

```
FARMER2CROP
f2c_id
farmer_id
crop_id
```

However some crops require a further sub-category look-up, e.g. spices (cumin, pepper, etc.)

Partly I think that all the spice sub-types should be part of the crops table, and maybe there should be a parent category, but the customer wants the spices to be a secondary look up, and the majority of crops do not have a parent type.

So I could have a third level many-to-many table joining to `farmers2crops:`

```
FARMERS2CROPS2SPICES
f2c_id
spice_id
```

But this seems a little convoluted, are there any suggestions for a better design here - or is this the best trade off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a trade off, this is [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I agree - I'm just wondering if it's the best approach here or if I should be more practical.

Comment: The only reason I would consider denormalizing my data is if there's a performance problem (think data warehouse). You can create VIEWS ad-infinitum to present the data in a tabular form you like best but I would not change the underlying structure for that.

Answer (score 1):

Logically you should have the following tables:

FARMER (farmer_id, ...)

CROP (crop_id,farmer_id, ...)

CROPSUB (cropsub_id, crop_id ...)

With these three tables you can connect through joins everything (three dots mean other possible table fields).

I hope that this is helpful to you.

Comment: Problem here is that farmers could potentially have many crops, hence the farmer2crop table.

Comment: I do not know if I get it right, but you can have a look again. I tried to edit the tables so that they will comply to what I believe is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would forget the `farmers2crops2spices` option, too complex for the need IMO.

Simple option: add a `subcategory` table + `crop.subcategory_id` column (NULLable).
However, you may end up with `subsubcategory`, `subsubsubcategory`, etc tables (+ `crop.subsubcategory_id`, etc.).

But I guess that what you will need for the long term is a [nested set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for your crop categories. I suggest to use an ORM like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) (if you use PHP) which will abstract all the hard stuff to use such a structure efficiently.

Comment: The problem is that there might be several crops that are categorized besides spices (e.g. fruits), so a nullable sub_cat_id in my farmers2crops table, wouldn't be ideal. Thanks for the nested sets list, I need to read up on that.

Comment: Just note that in my answer, I didn't suggest to add `sub_cat_id` field to `farmers2crop` table, but to `crop` table (I named that field `crop.subcategory_id`).